# Jquery ajax response in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, response

I have simple jquery/ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my_domain",
    type:"post",
    data: 'user_agent='+ window.navigator.userAgent+'&from='+self_loc,
    complete:function(res){
               console.log(res.responseText);
    }

})
```

in php i have just response one string like "test";

it work for chrome + firefox+opera
but don't work for IE8
Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

May be an issue with your MIME type. Try to set an header with the content type you will return to the browser. And you may also need to opt out IE8s MIME sniffing.

ex:

```
<?PHP
Header("Content-Type: text/plain");
Header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
echo "test";
```